# Documentation for adding new fonts to Android

Tags: android

Planning to add new Apache lincenced TTF fonts to support SE.Asian locales in Android Jelly Bean.

Looking through Android code tree. I found that 'Android/frameworks/base/data/fonts' is right place to add the files and modify the make files.

Is there any documentation I can refer to before submitting the patch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to patch fallback_fonts.mk and fonts.mk file and add your fonts.

Example given here:
http://review.cyanogenmod.org/#/c/29812/